# Solve the following matrix equation

Tags: matrices

What is the simplest way to solve such an equation?

$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}0&1&2&3 \\ 1&2&0&1\end{array}\right] \cdot \left[\begin{array}{c}x \\ y \\z \\ t\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0\end{array}\right]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's equivalent to solve the system :

$$\Bigg| \begin{matrix}
0x+1y+2z+3t=0 \\
1x+2y+0z+1t=0
\end{matrix}$$

Now there are $2$ equations and $4$ variables, so you need to pick $4-2=2$ parameters. Say $z = u$ and $t = v$. Then $y = -2u-3v$ and $x = -2(-2u-3v) - v = 4u + 5v$. So the final result is $(x,y,z,t) = (4u+5v, -2u-3v, u, v)$ for every $u, v \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Apply Gaussian elimination to the left matrix.